# Is there a htaccess rewrite rule wildcard?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to rewrite and redirect project/issues/(some_stuff_here) to i/(same_stuff_here) . I've been fumbling around with htaccess for a while now and I haven't gotten anywhere. I'd appreciate it if someone could write out the code I need (with some helpful comments explaining why something goes where it does). Thanks! :)

**EDIT:** I should have mentioned that I also need i/(same_stuff_here) to display everything on project/issues/(some_stuff_here).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `this rule` in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^project/issues/(.*)$ /i/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift reponse, I should have mentioned that I also need i/(same_stuff_here) to display everything on project/issues/(some_stuff_here).

Comment: Now it doesn't do anything at all... :/

Comment: What is location of above .htaccess? What is the path of /project and /i/ folders?

Comment: I'm using a CMS (drupal) so I'm unsure what the path of /project is, /i is non-existant, and the .htaccess file is in the root directory.

Comment: If this is Drupal then you need to make sure above rule is first rule in your main .htaccess. Also tell me what is full URL that didn't work for you.